# Optimizing this query based search

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

We have two N-bit numbers (0< N< 100000). We have to perform q queries (0< q<500000) over these numbers. The query can be of following three types:

- set_a idx x: Set A[idx] to x, where 0 <= idx < N, where A[idx] is idx'th least significant bit of A.
- set_b idx x: Set B[idx] to x, where 0 <= idx < N.
- get_c idx: Print C[idx], where C=A+B, and 0<=idx

Now, I have optimized the code to the best extent I can.

- First, I tried with an int array for a, b and c. For every update, I calculate c and return  the ith bit when queried. It was damn slow. Cleared 4/11 test cases only.
- I moved over to using boolean array. It was around 2 times faster than int array approach. Cleared 7/11 testcases.
- Next, I figured out that I need not calculate c for calculating idx th bit of A+B. I will just scan A and B towards right from idx until I find either a[i]=b[i]=0 or a[i]=b[i]=1. If a[i]=b[i]=0, then I just add up towards left to idx th bit starting with initial carry=0. And if a[i]=b[i]=1, then I just add up towards left to idx th bit starting with initial carry=1.
  This was faster but cleared only 8/11 testcases.
- Then, I figured out once, I get to the position i, a[i]=b[i]=0 or a[i]=b[i]=1, then I need not add up towards idx th position. If a[i]=b[i]=0, then answer is (a[idx]+b[idx])%2 and if a[i]=b[i]=1, then the answer is (a[idx]+b[idx]+1)%2. It was around 40% faster but still cleared only 8/11 testcases.

Now my question is how do get down those 3 'hard' testcases? I dont know what they are but the program is taking >3 sec to solve the problem.

Here is the code: http://ideone.com/LopZf

Comment: Doing it with ints should be a lot faster than bools, are you sure you implemented it correctly?

Comment: The wording of the question suggests that the questioner may not be packing the int arrays. If their original code has arrays of N ints, with each element either 0 or 1, they need to change it to arrays of N/32 ints, with each element in the range 0..2^32-1. Also, if they are asked for c[i], they need only add from the smallest j where a[j] or b[j] has been changed recently to i.

Comment: Replace (a[pos]+b[pos]+carry)%2 with a[pos]^b[pos]^carry if the compiler is not making that optimization for you

Comment: I dont why but here is the speed-up:
bool with (a[pos]+b[pos]+carry)%2 > bool with (a[pos]^b[pos]^carry)%2 > int with (a[pos]+b[pos]+carry)%2

Comment: If you do it with xor, the %2 is useless.

Comment: @harold - right! the whole point of my suggestion to use xor is to remove the potentially expensive mod operation. XOR is by its nature an addition modulo 2 operator. That is why the plus sign "+" is used in mathematics as an alternate symbol for XOR (exclusive disjunction).

Answer (score 0):

One possible optimization is to replace

```
(a[pos]+b[pos]+carry)%2
```

with

```
a[pos]^b[pos]^carry
```

The XOR operator (^) performs addition modulo 2, making the potentially expensive mod operation (%) unnecessary. Depending on the language and compiler, the compiler may make optimizations for you when doing a mod with a power of 2. But since you are micro-optimizing it is a simple change to make that removes dependence on that optimization being made for you behind the scenes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

This is just one suggestion that is simple to make. As others have suggested, using packed ints to represent your bit array will likely also improve what is probably the worst case test for your code. That would be the get_c function of the most significant bit, with either A or B (but not both) being 1 for all the other positions, requiring a scan of every bit position to the least significant bit to determine carry. If you were using packed ints for your bits, there would only be approximately 1/32 as many operations neccessary (assuming 32 bit ints). Using packed ints however would be a somewhat more complicated than your use of a simple boolean array (which really is likely just an array of bytes).

[C/C++ Bit Array or Bit Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604130/c-c-bit-array-or-bit-vector)

[Convert bit array to uint or similar packed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732237/convert-bit-array-to-uint-or-similar-packed-value)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array

There are lots of other examples on Stackoverflow and the net for using ints as if they were bit arrays.

Comment: Using xor instead of sum-modulo2 doesn't give any speedup. Re-writing code using packed ints. Will get back soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that looks a bit like your algorithm. I demonstrate it with bytes, but of course you can easily optimize the algorithm using 32 bit words (I suppose your machine has 64 bits arithmetic nowadays).

```
void setbit( unsigned char*x,unsigned int idx,unsigned int bit)
{
   unsigned int digitIndex = idx>>3;
   unsigned int bitIndex = idx & 7;
   if( ((x[digitIndex]>>bitIndex)&1) ^ bit) x[digitIndex]^=(1u<<bitIndex);
}
unsigned int getbit(unsigned char *a,unsigned char *b,unsigned int idx)
{
   unsigned int digitIndex = idx>>3;
   unsigned int bitIndex = idx & 7;
   unsigned int c = a[digitIndex]+b[digitIndex];
   unsigned int bit = (c>>bitIndex) & 1;
   /* a zero bit on the right will absorb a carry, let's check if any */
   if( (c^(c+1))>>bitIndex )
   {
      /* none, we must check if there's a carry propagating from the right digits */
      for(;digitIndex-- > 0;)
      {
         c=a[digitIndex]+b[digitIndex];
         if( c > 255 ) return bit^1; /* yes, a carry */
         if( c < 255 ) return bit;   /* no carry possible, a zero bit will absorb it */
      }
   }
   return bit;
}
```

If you find anything cryptic, just ask.
Edit: oops, I inverted the zero bit condition...