# What is a bit vector?

Tags: c

I looked online for a good while now, and can't seem to find a good example of what a bit vector actually is. 
I have an assignment to do for college which is to add, remove, union of 2 vectors and the intersection too. But I am struggling to comprehend what an actual bit vector is. I am using C to write this.
Could someone please help me on this, it would be a massive help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604130/c-c-bit-array-or-bit-vector

Comment: I saw this, but I didn't understand it, I'm looking for a better description...

Comment: A bit vector is a vector of bits.  It's a mathematical concept.  The implementation may take any number of different directions.

Answer (score 3):

Bit vector is a structure which purpose is an accessability of individual bits. Implementation-wise it can be an integer array with some function provided for addressing and manipulation of individual bits of the array. To the final user the array has to look as a "string" of bits, and the functions have to be able to access arbitrary nth bit of the "string".
There is a `bitset` class in the standard library of C++ which represent this concept, but I am not aware of some option in C language.