# Implementing set with a bit array

Tags: arrays, set

How I can use a bit array or a boolean array to implement a structure of set?
I don't know how I can include the bit array, I was thinking that this array has to
to remember which elements appear in the set.

Comment: Could you please, specify the programming language ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C/C++ Bit Array or Bit Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604130/c-c-bit-array-or-bit-vector)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.